# RASA: Sender_id always returned as “default”

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I’m using docker-compose for deploying Rasa. I faced an issue when I tried to retrieve the sender_id in actions it always returned as “default”

Please find my docker-compose below:

```
version: "3.4"

x-database-credentials: &database-credentials
  DB_HOST: "db"
  DB_PORT: "5432"
  DB_USER: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
  DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
  DB_LOGIN_DB: "${DB_LOGIN_DB:-rasa}"

x-rabbitmq-credentials: &rabbitmq-credentials
  RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
  RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
  RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}

x-redis-credentials: &redis-credentials
  REDIS_HOST: "redis"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"
  REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  REDIS_DB: "1"

x-duckling-credentials: &duckling-credentials
  RASA_DUCKLING_HTTP_URL: "http://duckling:8000"

services:
  rasa-production:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSION}-full"
    ports:
      - "5006:5005"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:
      - run
      - --cors
      - "*"
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
      <<: *redis-credentials
      <<: *rabbitmq-credentials
      DB_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
      RABBITMQ_QUEUE: "rasa_production_events"
      RASA_TELEMETRY_ENABLED: ${RASA_TELEMETRY_ENABLED:-true}

    depends_on:
      - app
      - rabbit
      - redis
      - db

  app:
    restart: always
    build: actions/.
    volumes:
      - ./actions:/app/actions
    expose:
      - "5055"
    environment:
      SERVICE_BASE_URL: "${SERVICE_BASE_URL}"
      RASA_SDK_VERSION: "${RASA_SDK_VERSION}"
    depends_on:
      - redis

  scheduler:
    restart: always
    build: scheduler/.
    environment:
      SERVICE_BASE_URL: "${SERVICE_BASE_URL}"
    
  duckling:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/duckling:0.1.6.3"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    command: ["duckling-example-exe", "--no-access-log", "--no-error-log"]
 
  # revers_proxy:
  #   image: nginx
  #   ports:
  #     - 80:80
  #     - 443:443
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./config/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  #   depends_on:
  #     - rasa-production
  #     - app

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.0
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  # revers_proxy:
  #   image: nginx
  #   ports:
  #     - 5006:5006
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./config/nginx/defaul.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  #   depends_on:
  #     - rasa-production
  #     - app

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/redis:6.0.8"
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "6379"

  redisapp:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/redis:6.0.8"
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    expose:
      - "6379"

  rabbit:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.9"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
      RABBITMQ_USERNAME: "user"
      RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
      RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_LIMIT: "{mem_relative, 0.1}"
    expose:
      - "5672"

  db:
    restart: always
    image: "bitnami/postgresql:11.9.0"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USER:-admin}"
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE:-rasa}"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/bitnami/postgresql
```

endpoints.yml file

```
tracker_store:
  type: sql
  dialect: "postgresql"
  url: ${DB_HOST}
  port: ${DB_PORT}
  username: ${DB_USER}
  password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  db: ${DB_DATABASE}
  login_db: ${DB_LOGIN_DB}
lock_store:
  type: "redis"
  url: ${REDIS_HOST}
  port: ${REDIS_PORT}
  password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  db: ${REDIS_DB}
event_broker:
  type: "pika"
  url: ${RABBITMQ_HOST}
  username: ${RABBITMQ_USERNAME}
  password: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
  queue: rasa_production_events
```

Rasa Version     : 2.1.0
Rasa SDK Version : 2.1.1
Rasa X Version   : None
Python Version   : 3.8.5
Operating System : Linux-5.4.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
Python Path      : /usr/bin/python3

Please any help to overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug described in this issue https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/7338